# Error: ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a lstm model for text classification and I'm receiving an error. This is my entire code that I've tried.

Please let me know what's the reason behind the error and how to fix it.

```
input1.shape # text data integer coded
(37788, 130)
input2.shape # multiple category columns(one hot encoded) concatenated together
(37788, 104)

train_data = [input1, input2] # this is the train data.

i1 = Input(shape=(130,), name='input')
embeddings = Embedding(input_dim=20000, output_dim=100, input_length=130)(i1)
lstm = LSTM(100)(embeddings)
flatten = Flatten()(lstm)

i2  = Input(shape=(None, 104))
c1 = Conv1D(64, 2, padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(i2)
c2 = Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(c1)
flatten1 = Flatten()(c2)

concat = concatenate([flatten, flatten1])
dense1 = Dense(32, 'relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(concat)
```

I tried to print shape of conv1d layers and I was getting None for flatten layer. I think it might be the reason for the error.

```
Tensor("conv1d_81/Identity:0", shape=(None, None, 64), dtype=float32)
Tensor("conv1d_82/Identity:0", shape=(None, None, 32), dtype=float32)
Tensor("flatten_106/Identity:0", shape=(None, None), dtype=float32)
```

This is the error I'm getting. How to fix it?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-531-31a53fbf3d37> in <module>
         14 concat = concatenate([flatten, flatten1])
    ---> 15 dense1 = Dense(32, 'relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(concat)
         16 drop = Dropout(0.5)(dense1)

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
        614           # Build layer if applicable (if the `build` method has been
        615           # overridden).
    --> 616           self._maybe_build(inputs)
        617 
        618           # Wrapping `call` function in autograph to allow for dynamic control

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in _maybe_build(self, inputs)
       1964         # operations.
       1965         with tf_utils.maybe_init_scope(self):
    -> 1966           self.build(input_shapes)
       1967       # We must set self.built since user defined build functions are not
       1968       # constrained to set self.built.

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py in build(self, input_shape)
       1003     input_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(input_shape)
       1004     if tensor_shape.dimension_value(input_shape[-1]) is None:
    -> 1005       raise ValueError('The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` '
       1006                        'should be defined. Found `None`.')
       1007     last_dim = tensor_shape.dimension_value(input_shape[-1])

    ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.
```

Comment: if `Dense` is first layer then you have to set shape/size of input data. You can see it even  in example in [Dense documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense)

Comment: @furas But I have few other layers right at the front like LSTM, Embedding as you can see in my code above I also have two conv1d layers and two flatten layers before I come to Dense layer. Right?

Comment: when you use `Dense()` in `Sequential()` then it automatically gets shape from previous `Dense()` and only first `Dense()` needs shape - like in example in documentation - but you may have to set this shape manually `Dense(... input_shape=...)`

Comment: @furas How can I know what will be the shape after it passes through all the before layers like embedding layer, lstm, flatten, conv1d, flatten, concatenate layer? It is not my first layer. I'm using keras functional api and It also automatically gets shape from previous layers just like sequential model.You just have to pass it like I did. Dense(100)(x) here x refer to previous layer. I can't figure out why i'm getting an error here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have `None` in the length of the sequence in the second model.

```
i2  = Input(shape=(None, 104))
```

You can't flatten a variable length and have a known size.
You need a known size for `Dense`.

Either you use a fixed length instead of `None`, or you use a `GlobalMaxPooling1D` or a `GlobalAveragePooling1D` instead of `Flatten`.

Comment: What should I fill in place of None here? Is it my input2 shape?

Comment: Yes. It's input2 shape.

Comment: Now I get this error during model.fit  `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (37788, 104)` Why does it expect my input 1 to have 3 dimensions?

Comment: I combined both input1 and input2 as `train_data = [input1, input2]` and passed it as x to model.fit

Comment: Because you said your input would have 3 dimensions in `i2` with shape `(batch, None, 104)`

Comment: Can you tell me how do I fix it? It's not a 3d. (input 2 is concatenation of  multiple categorical features one hot encoded). I have given `i2  = Input(shape=(37788, 104))`. I haven't specified None.

Comment: What is 37788? Length or samples?

Comment: It's number of data points (37788 samples) and 104 are features.

Comment: Then `shape=(104,)`

Comment: That is giving this error `ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv1d_13 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 104]`

Comment: That's because Conv1D needs 3d arrays `(samples, length, features)`, not 2d. I don't know what you want to achieve, but you must understand your data and what you want to extract from it.

Comment: If you want to treat your 104 features as a sequence, you could try to reshape your array to `(37788, 104, 1)` and use `shape=(104,1)`. But this would only make sense if the features have similar nature and something could be extracted from treating them like a sequence.

Comment: "But this would only make sense if the features have similar nature" can you explain what you meant by that? I had 5 categorical columns and I've used one hot encoder on each of the column and then combined all of them using `np.c_[cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4, cat5]` here cal1,2,3.. are one hot encoded. This returned the shape of `(37788, 104)`

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that i did not reshape the Tensor before use in the input function

```
image = tf.reshape(image, [400,400,3])
```