# Tensorflow: How to convert string inputs to numbers on the fly while training the model using a custom string_to_number function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, preprocessor

#### Context

I have a dataframe containing strings and labels. I have a specific set of rules (I define a `string_to_number` function and an encoding dictionary) to convert the string value to a NumPy array of numbers. In the example below, I am converting the strings to NumPy arrays of RGB values. The code below uses 1 pixel for each string character, but I want this to be customizable. I want to train a `conv1d` based neural network to perform classification based on the labels.

#### Problem

How to use my `string_to_number` function so that it can convert the string inputs to NumPy array on the fly, and feed it to the model? Also need optional ability to pad the data with zeros at the batch, or the entire dataset, level. Do I even need to pad for a convolutional operation?

EDIT 1:  Most errors I get with the approaches I've tried are after the `fit` is called. So kindly make sure that the solution works with the `fit`.

### Example code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

STRINGS = ['ABC', 'C', 'BA', 'AC', 'CAB']
LABELS = [0, 1, 2, 1, 3]

# create a dataframe with two columns, string and labels
df = pd.DataFrame({'string': STRINGS, 'label': LABELS})
df
```

Outputs:

```
  string  label
0    ABC      0
1      C      1
2     BA      2
3     AC      1
4    CAB      3
```

Encoding rules and function:

```
ENCODING_DICT = {'A':[255, 0, 0], 'B':[0, 255, 0], 'C':[0, 0, 255]}

def string_to_number(
    string:str,
    encoding_dict:dict,
    pixels_per_character:int=1, # didn't use for the sake of simplicity
    pad_length:int=4):

    encoded_array = np.array([encoding_dict[char] for char in string])
    padded_array = np.zeros((1, 4, 3))
    padded_array[0, :encoded_array.shape[0], :] = encoded_array
    return padded_array
```

Test the function

```
string_to_number(STRINGS[0], ENCODING_DICT)
```

Outputs:

```
array([[[255.,   0.,   0.],
        [  0., 255.,   0.],
        [  0.,   0., 255.],
        [  0.,   0.,   0.]]])
```

Model and fit

```
# create a model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # WHAT DO I DO HERE ________
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(3, 1, input_shape=(_____)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')
])
# compile and fit the model
model.compile ________
model.fit(df['string'], df['label'], ________)
```

#### Approaches I tried

Too many errors/trials to go into detail here, but I hope that those details are not required for someone who has built such an input pipeline before.

- Used a `lambda` function inside `tf.data.Dataset.map`.
- Used a custom preprocessing head as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe#full_example).
- A data generator with the `tf.data.Dataset.from_generator` method. I haven't implemented this yet, because the documentation cautions about this method's constraints.

#### Note:

1. The dataset is large and the `string_to_number` conversion is expensive on the memory/disk. So it is important to do this on the fly.
2. The encoding function and the mapping dictionary are more complicated than shown here.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

class TensorLookup:
  def __init__(self, keys, encoding):
    self.keys = keys
    self.encoding = encoding
    self.table = tf.lookup.StaticHashTable(
    tf.lookup.KeyValueTensorInitializer(self.keys, tf.range(tf.shape(self.keys)[0])),
    default_value=-1)
  
  def lookup(self, key):
    index = self.table.lookup(key)
    return tf.gather(self.encoding, index)

class PreprocessLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
      super(PreprocessLayer, self).__init__()

    def call(self, inputs):
      x = tf.squeeze(tf.strings.bytes_split(tf.strings.lower(inputs)), axis=1)
      return encoding_dict.lookup(x).to_tensor()

encoding = tf.constant([[255, 0, 0],                   
                        [0, 255, 0],
                        [0, 0, 255]], dtype=tf.float32)

encoding_dict = TensorLookup(keys = tf.constant(['a', 'b', 'c']), encoding = encoding)


STRINGS = ['ABC', 'C', 'BA', 'AC', 'CAB']
LABELS = [0, 1, 2, 1, 3]
df = pd.DataFrame({'string': STRINGS, 'label': LABELS})

preprocess_layer = PreprocessLayer()
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(1, ), dtype=tf.string),
    preprocess_layer,
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(3, 1),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(df['string'].to_numpy()[..., None], df['label'], batch_size=2, epochs=5)
```

Since you cannot flatten a variable length tensor, I am using `GlobalMaxPooling1D`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918388/error-valueerror-the-last-dimension-of-the-inputs-to-dense-should-be-defined) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to suggest this. I am currently unable to test this approach as my tensorflow conda environment decided to break. I will update asap.

Comment: This works the way you've implemented. But doesn't if I use my own `string_to_number` python function. I get errors like 'cannot iterate over a tensor'. The actual function I need to use is more elaborate and can't be translated to a `lookup` I think. Do you know of a way to implement this using the python function?